# Is this Integral transformation correct?

Tags: normal-distribution, lebesgue-integral

I have an Integral:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{-y_1} \Phi(y_2)d\Phi(x_1)
$$

Here:

$\Phi(y_2)$ is the Gaussian density function of variable '$y_2$' which has to be integrated w.r.t Gaussian density of another '$x_1$' and the upper limit is another variable $y_1$.

I have the identity:
$$y_2 = y_1 + x_1$$

Essentially $x_1$, $y_1$, are arguments of the respective PDFs of two independent Normal Random Variables $X_1$ and $Y_1$ and integral becomes:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{-y_1} \Phi(y_1+x_1)d\Phi(x_1)
$$

Now, changing $\Phi(y_1+x_1) = u$, I have:
$$
d\Phi(x_1) = du\tag{A}\\
$$
When $x_1=-\infty,\; \Phi(-\infty)=0=u\tag{B}$
$x_1=-y_1,\; \Phi(0) = \frac{1}{2}=u\tag{C}$

Integral becomes:
$$
\int_0^{1\over2}udu
$$

Which seems to work for my calculations but, essentially, are steps (A) through (C) correct?

Comment: Any guidance will be appreciated. As this would mean generalization of some very important results.

Comment: The expectation is $$\frac12-\frac12\Phi^2(-y/\sqrt2)+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Phi(-y).$$ The change of variable in your post does not yield (A).